# access a member of class using vector

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a class defined as

```
typedef std::string Name;
typedef int Age;
typedef std::string Level;

class Employee
{
public:
    // Employee (arguments);
    //  virtual ~Employee ();
    void name(Name const & name) { name_ = name; }
    Name name() const { return name_; }

    void age(Age const & age) { age_ = age; }
    Age age() const { return age_; }

    void level(Level const & level) { level_ = level; }
    Level level() const { return level_; }

private:
    Name name_;
    Age age_;
    Level level_;
};

std::vector<Employee> read_file(std::string filename);

std::vector<Employee> employees = read_file("data.txt");
std::cout << employees.size() << std:: endl;

for(std::vector<Employee>::iterator it = employees.begin(); it != employees.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;  
}
```

Is there a way for me to access the members of the class Employee using this vector defined above? I want to construct a `map` container with level of the employee as the key value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm misinterpreting your question, this is simple enough.

- `it` is an iterator over the vector of `Employee`.
- `*it` is the `Employee`
- `it->` lets you access members of that `Employee`

  - e.g.:  `it->name()`

So, if you want to build a map of employee level to `Employee`, you can do this:

```
std::map<Level, Employee> employeeMap;
for(std::vector<Employee>::iterator it = employees.begin();
    it != employees.end();
    ++it)
{
  employeeMap[ it->level() ] = *it;
}
```

Now you have your employeeMap, which maps the employee's `Level` to the `Employee`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to access members of `Employee` from the iterator you can use the member access operator `->`:

```
the_map[it->level()] = blah;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 const Name name   = it->name();
 const Age age     = it->age();
 const Level level = it->level();
```

or

```
 const Name name   = employees[i].name();
 const Age age     = employees[i].age();
 const Level level = employees[i].level();
```

will work fine.

I would, however, strongly recommend you return each of the above items as references as it will generally be a lot faster than making a copy of the object.

ie

```
class Employee
{
public:
    // Employee (arguments);
    //  virtual ~Employee ();
    void name(Name const & name) { name_ = name; }
    Name& name() { return name_; }
    const Name& name() const { return name_; }

    void age(Age const & age) { age_ = age; }
    Age& age() { return age_; }
    const Age& age() const { return age_; }

    void level(Level const & level) { level_ = level; }
    Level& level() { return level_; }
    const Level& level() const { return level_; }
private:
    Name name_;
    Age age_;
    Level level_;
};
```

Then you can access the values by reference as follows:

```
 const Name& name   = it->name();
 const Age& age     = it->age();
 const Level& level = it->level();
```

It also means you can change the values like this:

```
 it->name()  = "Goz";
 it->age()   = 33;
 it->level() = "Programmer";
```

Comment: I highly recommend NOT returning reference from a const member.  Return reference from non-const version, and const reference from const function.

Comment: And if you're returning reference from a non-const member, the object might as well be public.  If it's private, you don't want that.  Just do the const reference version.

Comment: If you're going to return a reference from a const method, you'd better return a `const` reference.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Ooops just me being blind ;)  Yeah it would either have to not be a const function (as I modified it too) or you'd need to return a const object.  Generally I'd advise having both ...

Comment: @Goz: You'd advise returning a member by (nonconst) reference rather than making it public?  Oh right, encapsulation.  Yeah, do that.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Yeah thats basically it.  I generally find it make refactorisation on a change a HELL of a lot easier.